# scrapy not entering parse(response.url)

Tags: selenium, parsing, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm a beginner. When I crawl, there is no error code, but scrapy does not enter `response.url` in parse. That is, the page is empty page titled "data;"
how to enter the repsonse.url?

```
import scrapy
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import time

from result_crawler.items import RESULT_Item

class RESULT_Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name="EPL"
    allowed_domains=["premierleague.com"]
    starts_urls=["https://www.premierleague.com/match/38567"]

    def __init__(self):
        scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
        self.browser=webdriver.Chrome("/users/germpark/chromedriver")

    def parse(self,response):
        self.browser.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(5)
.
.
.
```

I want to enter `https://www.premierleague.com/match/38567` but result did not exist.

Comment: Why are you using Selenium?

Comment: If you really need proper Selenium integration, have a look at: https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium

Comment: thanks to your quick answer my code works well now. In fact, I don't know well computer knowledge. Motivation is just preview.. I should be an army soon because I'm korean, duty, So before become, I wanted to play a project, sports data crawling.

Comment: if i have enough time, i try to get too many imformation before project. As a result, my crawler works well. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The correct property name is `start_urls` not `starts_urls`. Because of the incorrect property name it does not detect any start pages.

Comment: (just small typo: `start_urls` instead of `start_url`)

Comment: @vezunchik Thanks! I fixed it. What a stupid typo when trying to fix a typo.